# Why is my react unit test import not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

The **navList.js** is correct when I run `npm run watch`.

But when I try to run `npm test`, the log only shows `setArticleGroup: 1` ( `setArticleGroup: 2` and `setArticleGroup: 3` are missing ).

I realize that `getArticlesFromDatabase` is not work in test, why is this the case?

**navList.test.js**

```
it('function setArticleGroup() ', function () {
    let app = shallow(<NavList sieve="info" />);
});
```

**navList.js**

```
import {getArticlesFromDatabase} from '../csrfData';

setArticleGroup(){
    let that = this;
    console.log('setArticleGroup: 1   ');

    getArticlesFromDatabase.then(function(value) {
        console.log('setArticleGroup: 2   ');

        ...//skip

        that.setState({'articleGroup':articleGroup},()=>{
            console.log('setArticleGroup: 3   ',articleGroup);
        });
    });
}
```

**csrfData.js**

```
var getArticlesFromDatabase = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let articles;
    axios.get('../api/articles/get-articles-list').then(response=>{
        articles = response.data.list;
        resolve(articles);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});

export {getArticlesFromDatabase,testCsrfData};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `getArticlesFromDatabase` is an object with a `then` function as property, I'd say you should be calling it like this (note the parens):

```
getArticlesFromDatabase().then(function(value) {
```

Comment: what do you mean? If I change getArticlesFromDatabase.then(function(value) {}) to getArticlesFromDatabase().then(function(value) {}), it will get error.

Comment: I thought that `getArticlesFromDatabase` would be a promise returning function, since `then` was appended to it. I can't figure out more without seeing the code imported from `csrfData`.

Comment: Hello, sorry for reply so late. I already add csrfData.js, plz help.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I don't know how you've configured axios to handle HTTP errors, but in case they're not throwing an error maybe you can check what status code is being returned in the .then function: `console.log(response.status)`.

Comment: Thanks for advice, you are right that issue is come from catch. So I new a qusetion which I think is the main problem. Thanks for help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48658252/unit-test-how-to-mock-axios-in-react